# Manually render filter form fields in layout

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, jform, filter

I am using the searchtools filters in the front end of a custom component.

So I am displaying the fields in my template :

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default', array('view' => $this)); ?>
```

Everything works fine but in the mobile and tablet the searchtools shows only the search field and hides everything else. 
I do not want this. Is a custom component so I want to display all the filters even in mobile in a element that I control his visibility.

So I decided to render the fields the way I like in my **tmpl/default.php** file.
The problem is that no field is rendering.

Here is the code :
In the view :

```
$this->filterForm = $this->get('FilterForm');
JLog::add('filterform: ' . print_r($this->filterForm, TRUE), JLog::DEBUG, 'com_contract-site-ContractView');
```

And the log

```
DEBUG 127.0.0.1 com_contract-site-contractview  filterform: Joomla\CMS\Form\Form Object
(
    [data:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
        (
            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [list] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [limit] => 20
                        )
                )
            [initialized:protected] => 
            [separator] => .
        )    
    [xml:protected] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => filter
                                )    
                            [field] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => search
                                                    [type] => text
                                                    [label] => COM_CONTRACT_CONTRACTS_SEARCH_IN_TITLE
                                                    [hint] => JSEARCH_FILTER
                                                    [class] => js-stools-search-string
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => published
                                                    [type] => status
                                                    [label] => JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED
                                                    [description] => JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED_DESC
                                                    [onchange] => this.form.submit();
                                                )

                                            [option] => JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED
                                        )
                                    )
                        )
                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => list
                                )

                            [field] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => limit
                                            [type] => limitbox
                                            [class] => input-mini
                                            [default] => 25
                                            [label] => COM_CONTENT_LIST_LIMIT
                                            [description] => COM_CONTRACT_LIST_LIMIT_DESC
                                            [onchange] => this.form.submit();
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [repeat] => 
)
```

So I got all the fields, but no field is rendered.

**tmpl/default.php**

```
<?php echo $this->filterForm->renderField('search'); ?>
<?php echo $this->filterForm->renderField('published'); ?>
<?php echo $this->filterForm->renderField('clientlist'); ?>
```

etc ...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include group name as the second parameter in `renderField()`, e.g.:

```
echo $this->filterForm->renderField('published', 'filter');
echo $this->filterForm->renderField('limit', 'list');
```

Or if you want to run a loop:

```
foreach ($this->filterForm->getGroup('filter') as $field)
{
    echo $field->renderField();
}
```

Also, you could create a custom version of `/layouts/joomla/searchtools/default.php` in your component's folder and remove the CSS classes there. If you maintain the folder structure, it will be able to load default sublayouts without having to copy them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The group is what was missing !
Now for the searchtools layout I wanted to avoid it because is a component. I will not be able to know which template is going to be used or another template will be installed in the future.